How does new Windows 11 laptop have Bluetooth driver from the past?
I got a new Windows 11 laptop a few months ago. My previous laptop was Windows 10 and Bluetooth worked flawlessly, but this new laptop has had non-stop problems. (Example: I always have to turn off Bluetooth and put the laptop on standby and then vice-versa a total of twice for my Bluetooth headphones to work, and after only a few minutes of inactivity I have to repeat this all over again).
While trying to solve the problem, I went into Device Manager, and stumbled upon a Bluetooth driver for a device I have not used in a long time: SoundCore mini.

I have last used my SoundCore mini device around 9 months ago. This laptop is approximately 3 months old. I don't even know where my SoundCore mini is right now. Even if I had miraculously turned it on by accident at some point in the last few months, I certainly have never gone as far as pairing it with my new laptop.
Can anyone explain the mysteriousness of this driver being on my new laptop? Is Windows 11 perhaps syncing drivers with my old laptop which had this driver?
Who knows, maybe this is related to the Bluetooth issues I've been having.

Are you logged in with your Microsoft account? If so there are some sync happening in the background. That said, whether this is the case or not, it has nothing to do with your supposed problems.

@ChanganAuto It appears I am logged in to a Microsoft account. But driver syncing is hardly a thing? That sounds extremely error-prone.

One theory is that if the SoundCore mini was put under power, Windows might have detected it, and still remembers it today although pairing was never done. For the problems, I suggest to test Windows integrity by running the commands Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth and then sfc /scannow.

BT issues can arise from a variety of things, including a subpar BT card or signal interference. Have you tried a repair install of Windows (open Windows Setup's setup.exe while boot to Windows, choosing to Keep all files and settings)?


Though when you purchased the laptop, Window 11 was the OS, it might have been installed by the OEM or vendor over another OS (e.g., Win 10). The is commonly done so the PC is sold (comparatively) up-to-date.

Perhaps Windows 11 installs that slew of drivers in the hope one would work on that PC model. You can confirm this by installing Windows 11 from ISO (or from the OEM recovery media, if provided) to an empty drive (though I doubt the knowledge would be worth that effort).

When you click on SoundCore mini, select properties, and Update Driver, is a newer version installed? Perhaps an update is needed.



